# Echo tags with an if statement and display php inside of the IF?

Tags: tags, conditional-tags

I am having issues displaying tags only if there is tags and including php inside of it as well.   This is what I tried but nothing is showing.

```
<?php
if( has_tag() ) { ?>

    <!-- Start of tags -->

        <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'download_tag', 'Tags ', ', ', '' ); ?>

    <!-- End of tags  -->

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The has_tag function doesn't do what you expect here. It actually means 'post has tag' checks if a post (or current post) has a particular tag. Something like `has_tag( 'self-important-tag' )`. [See the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag)

If you leave out the conditional and the post has no tags, get_the_termlist will echo nothing because it checks if the post has terms internally:

```
<!-- Start of tags -->
    <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'download_tag', 'Tags ', ', ', '' ); ?>
<!-- End of tags  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your condition, try this:

```
<?php 
    $var = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'download_tag', 'Tags ', ', ', '' );
    echo $var;
?>
```

[I have not tested this!]